# Windows Phone adding item to end of ListBox with different DataTemplate?

Tags: c#, list, xaml, listbox, windows-phone

I want to add a "all items" button to the end of the ListBox in Windows Phone.
How can I do this?

I want its DataTemplate to be different then the rest of the ListBox items!

Answer (score 1):

Use an `ItemTemplateSelector` witch based on Item type will show different `DataTemplate`.
You can follow following guide:
http://www.geekchamp.com/articles/implementing-windows-phone-7-datatemplateselector-and-customdatatemplateselector

Answer (score 1):

Don't use item template selectors for that: using them just for a single button is an overkill, besides they're harder to implement and support.

Instead, you should customize the control template of your list box. In blend, right click on a list box, "Edit Template / Edit a copy...", than in the template change the XAML `<ScrollViewer><ItemsPresenter /></ScrollViewer>` into e.g. `<ScrollViewer><StackPanel><ItemsPresenter /><Button Content="all items" /></StackPanel></ScrollViewer>`